# ws:outbound-gateway adds extra SOAP envelope and Header to the message

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am new to spring integration and spring boot. And, my use case is to poll for a message in a JMS queue and call another web service by using the message payload XML coming from JMS queue. The XML payload contains the SOAP envelope,body and SAML headers.

I can hit the web service with the XML payload using SOAP UI tool.

This is my spring integration configuration file.

====================================================

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xmlns:ws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws"
    xmlns:stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws/spring-integration-ws.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd">
    <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn"
            destination-name="requestQueue"
            channel="jmsInChannel"
            error-channel = "error-Channel" />


<channel id="error-Channel"/>
<stream:stdout-channel-adapter id="error-Channel"/>

<channel id="jmsInChannel">
    <interceptors>
        <wire-tap channel="loggerChannel"/>
    </interceptors>
</channel>

<logging-channel-adapter id="loggerChannel" level="INFO"/>

<beans:bean id="MY.SOAP-MessageSender"
  class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
  <beans:property name="connectionTimeout" value="30000" />
  <beans:property name="readTimeout" value="50000" />
 </beans:bean>
    <chain input-channel="jmsInChannel" output-channel="outChannel">
        <header-enricher>
             <header name="Content-Type" value="text/xml;charset=UTF-8" />
             <header name="SOAPAction" value="soapaction"/>
        </header-enricher>
        <ws:outbound-gateway  message-sender="MY.SOAP-MessageSender" uri="http://localhost:8080/soapws-endpoint"/>
    </chain>

    <!-- The response from the service is logged to the console. -->
    <!-- <stream:stdout-channel-adapter id="outChannel"/> -->
    <channel id="outChannel">
        <interceptors>
            <wire-tap channel="loggerChannel2"/>
        </interceptors>
    </channel>
<logging-channel-adapter id="loggerChannel2" level="INFO"/> 

<beans:bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <!-- brokerURL, You may have different IP or port -->
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
</beans:bean>

  <!-- Spring JMS Template -->
  <beans:bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate" >

    <beans:property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>

  </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

=============================================================

I can see that Spring is adding extra SOAP envelope and Header to the existing XML payload (which already has the SOAP envelope and payload).

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:head="http://header" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://typ">
   <soapenv:Header>
.
.
. WS security hader
     </soapenv:Header>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**Question:**
How do I remove the extra SOAP envelope and SOAP Header that are getting added. Is there any out of the box property in the configurations that I can use. If not, Please provide a sample code that I can make use of.
Please help...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That how it's designed; you only need to send the contents and the gateway will add the SOAP envelope. It's based on [Spring Web Services](http://projects.spring.io/spring-ws/).

If you want to roll your own SOAP processing, use a simple http outbound gateway instead.

Comment: If you need to inject custom SOAP headers, check this http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.M6/reference/html/ws.html#ws-message-headers in the end about `DefaultSoapHeaderMapper`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gary. I have used the following configuration

```
<header-enricher input-channel="jmsInChannel"
output-channel="jmsOutChannel">
             <header name="Content-Type" value="text/xml;charset=UTF-8" />
             <header name="SOAPAction" value="soapaction"/>
        </header-enricher>
        <int:channel id="jmsOutChannel" />
<http:outbound-gateway  extract-request-payload="true" id="webservice.outbound.gateway" request-channel="jmsOutChannel" reply-channel="celsiusChannel" url="http://localhost:8080/soa-ws" expected-response-type="java.lang.String" />
```

in place of

```
<chain input-channel="jmsInChannel" output-channel="celsiusChannel">
        <header-enricher>
             <header name="Content-Type" value="text/xml;charset=UTF-8" />
             <header name="SOAPAction" value="soapaction"/>
        </header-enricher>
        <ws:outbound-gateway  message-sender="MY.SOAP-MessageSender" uri="http://localhost:8080/soa-ws"/>
    </chain>
```

I think the attribute extract-request-payload="true" of http:outbound-gateway did the trick. Now the extra SOAP header and envelope are not getting added.